# Powershell replace characters at position x

Tags: string, performance, powershell, replace

```
Powershell 5.x
```

There is a string `$s`, approximately 2.5 KB long.
I need to run a series of replacements (about 20) on it, in a loop.
There are some `800K` strings like that in total so I need this to be *fast*.
For each replacement, I know position `[int] $x` and new value `[string] $ns`.

Example:
We start with `$s == "abcdefghijklmn"` and the `$x (position)` is 3, and a new value to put there is `$ns == "XYZ"`
We end up with `$s == "abcXYZghijklmn"`
(strings are indexed 0-based)

My solution so far:

```
$s = "abcdefghijklmn"
$ns = "XYZ"
$x = 3
$s = $s.Remove($x, $ns.Length).Insert($x, $ns)
```

This is at least three operations: removal of a string then insertion of a new string and finally storing the final result (not sure about internals here but I assume this is how things work). For 800K strings of 2.5KB len each we're talking about ~2GB of data being processed *three* times in memory. That's not the most effective way of doing things.

In Python, with MutableString, I can do in-place replacement with minimal cost. Does a similar thing exist in Powershell?

Comment: I'd say no, PowerShell isn't the fastest language out there. It's meant for system administration and operates at a fairly "high level"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my take using the Stringbuilder class.

```
$s = "abcdefghijklmn" -as [system.text.stringbuilder]
$ns = "XYZ"
$x = 3

$s.Replace($s.tostring().substring($x,$ns.length),$ns,$x,$ns.length).tostring()
```

Comment: Funny, I came up with a StringBuilder-based solution before you posted your answer. Probably the most natural approach as StringBuilder implements mutable strings. Well done.

Answer (score 0):

How about reconstructing the string instead ?

```
$s.Substring(0,$x) + $ns + $s.Substring($x)
```

Not sure if it's faster, might be worth checking on all the strings you have. You could also run things in parallel with foreach to speed up the process.

Answer (score 0):

This should be faster. You should convert the input string to a char array once before the replacements and convert it back to a string when all replacements are done:

```
$s  = ("abcdefghijklmn").ToCharArray()
$ns = ("XYZ").ToCharArray()
$x  = 3
0..($ns.Length-1) | ForEach-Object { $s[$x + $_] = $ns[$_] }

$result = [String]::new($s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another alternative. It uses Regular Expression.

```
$s  = "abcdefghijklmn"
$ns = "XYZ"
$x  = 3

$s -replace "(?m)^(.{$x}).(.+)", "`$1$ns`$2"
```

Regex details:

> ```
>     ^       Assert position at the beginning of a line (at beginning of the string or after a line break character)
> (           Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
>    .        Match any single character that is not a line break character
>       {3}   Exactly 3 times
> )
> .           Match any single character that is not a line break character
> (           Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 2
>    .        Match any single character that is not a line break character
>       +     Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
> )
> ```

You'd have to test yourself which of the offered solutions is the fastest in your situation.